# Anoying overbrighted element in the Volume component

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I open the **DefauldSceneRoot** in a **HDRP template** of a Unity project, you can see the *Scene view* extreamly over brighted in certain points of views. Like this:

[image: image1]

But the *Game view* looks correctly:

[image: image2]

Moving the camera out, you can find this sphere that is linked with the **Volume** component of the *Sky and Fog Volume*. And it's over brighted when the *Weight* variable of the Volume component has a value of 1:

[image]

If you change this value, seems that the bright goes normal, but This don't solve the problem when you aproach another time to the center point of the scene:

[image]

Is there any solution for this? I can't work with this conditions :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the volume **DefauldSettings** have the **Exposure** set to **Automatic**.

If you change it to **Fixed**, the realtime lights will work properly. Another option is create a new volume in your scene and override the exposure configuration.